# Haskell take multiple input and outputs in a do block

Tags: haskell, recursion, io

I have been trying to take an input and output a list onto the console in the same do block and then for this function to be repeated through recursion, but I'm new to IO in haskell and can't see how to get it to work.

Also I'm not putting an break statement on the recursion because I can just break it by pressing control-c in the console when I'm done using it.

My code:

```
move2 m coords char = when (can_move m coords char) (print_maze (place_player m (move coords char)))

game_loop m coords = print_maze (place_player m coords)
    do 
        (char:chars) <- getLine
        maze2 <- move2 m coords (read char)
        putStrLn maze2
        putStrLn game_loop m coords
```

The line before the do block is meant to output a list, but not be repeated in the recursion.

Error Message:

```
Unexpected do block in function application:
        do (char : chars) <- getLine
           maze2 <- move2 m coords (read char)
           putStrLn maze2
           putStrLn game_loop m coords
    You could write it with parentheses
    Or perhaps you meant to enable BlockArguments?
    |
107 |     do
    |     ^^^^...
```

It says this is the only error but I'm sure theres other errors in the do block aswell. All of the other individual functions work fine by themselves.

I don't know how I would fix this so any information in IO would be appreciated, thank you.

Edit:

I got the do block to work now I just have a type error.

```
move2 m coords char = when (can_move m coords char) (print_maze (place_player m (move coords char)))

game_loop m coords = do
    print_maze (place_player m coords)
    let loop = do 
        (char:chars) <- getLine
        maze2 <- move2 m coords (char)
        putStrLn maze2
        if char /= 'c'
        then game_loop m coords
        else return ()
    loop
```

Error message:

```
Couldn't match type `()' with `[Char]'
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: ()
    * In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely `maze2'
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn maze2
      In the expression:
        do (char : chars) <- getLine
           maze2 <- move2 m coords (char)
           putStrLn maze2
           if char /= 'c' then game_loop m coords else return ()
    |
111 |         putStrLn maze2
    |                  ^^^^^
```

Comment: It looks like you `move2` returns `IO ()` instead of `IO String`, and that copes with `putStrLn` requiring a string. Also, are you sure about `then game_loop ...`? You probably want only `loop` there. If the loop requires new values for the variables, then you need to turn `loop` into a function as in `let loop x y z = do .... ; .... then loop newX newY newZ`.

Comment: Re: your edit, it looks like `move2` is of type `IO ()`, which means that `maze2` is `()` (a.k.a. "unit"). `putStrLn` is `String -> IO ()`, so unit is not a valid first argument (rather, `putStrLn` expects a `String`). You could say `print maze2` or equivalently `putStrLn $ show maze2`, but I'm not sure why you would want to, since it would just print `()`. Perhaps you mean for `move2` to return something else?

Comment: On a side note, it's generally good practice to annotate your top-level functions with explicit types. This serves a dual purpose: makes it obvious to others (and your future self!) what sort of type transformation the function performs, and also helps confirm during development that you are writing the function you think you're writing. In this case, if you expect `move2` to have a return type other than `IO ()`, an explicit annotation would have caught the error and prevented that function from compiling in a vacuum. Instead, you're seeing the error elsewhere, which is less obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a line before a `do` block like that. If you want to do something before starting a loop, follow this scheme instead:

```
example :: IO ()
example = do
   putStrLn "this is the line before the loop, to be run once"
   let loop = do
          putStrLn "here we are inside the loop"
          if someCondition
          then loop      -- repeat the loop
          else return () -- stop the loop
   loop -- start the loop defined above
```

Comment: Thank you I'll test it with this layout and see if I can get it to work

Comment: I got the do block to work now I just have a type error.
 
print_maze (place_player m coords)
    let loop = do 
        (char:chars) <- getLine
        maze2 <- move2 m coords (char)
        putStrLn maze2
        if char /= 'c'
        then game_loop m coords
        else return ()
    loop


Couldn't match type `()' with `[Char]'
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: ()

This error is on the putStrLn maze2 line

Comment: @BigMan Edit your question adding the new code at the end. It's unreadable when put in a comment.

Comment: Sorry didn't realise the format changed like that its on the edit thank you